# MongoDB - OR function with a lot of conditions

Tags: java, mongodb, mongodb-query

I'm having a strange behavior when I make a MongoDB query with a lot of conditions in an $or function.

Basically what happens is that 100 results are cycled instantaneously in the DBCursor, and the following 5000 results are cycled just after 2 minutes!

Here’s the code (method that makes the query):

```
public Object getMongoData(String aDbName, String aCollectionName, DBObject aQueryObj, DBObject aSortObj, boolean aFindOne,
  DBObject aFieldsFilter, int aLimitStartPosition, int aLimitNumberResults, boolean aCreateIndex) throws Exception
  {
    // String aDbName MY_DB
    // String aCollectionName = MY_COLLECTION
    // DBObject aQueryObj = {"$or":[{"_id":"id1"},…,{"_id":"id5000"}]}
    // DBObject aSortObj = null
    // boolean aFindOne = false
    // DBObject aFieldsFilter = null
    // int aLimitStartPosition = 0
    // int aLimitNumberResults = 0
    // boolean aCreateIndex = false

    Object resultObj = null;
    DBObject query;
    DBObject filter;

    if (aQueryObj == null)
    {
      query = new BasicDBObject();
    }
    else
    {
      query = aQueryObj;
    }

    if (aFieldsFilter == null)
    {
      filter = new BasicDBObject();
    }
    else
    {
      filter = aFieldsFilter;
    }

    DBCollection collection = loadCollection(aDbName, aCollectionName);
    if (collection != null)
    {
      if (aFindOne)
      {
        resultObj = collection.findOne(query, filter);
      }
      else
      {
        if ((aSortObj != null) && !aSortObj.keySet().isEmpty())
        {
          if (aCreateIndex)
          {
            collection.createIndex(aSortObj);
          }

          resultObj = collection.find(query, filter).skip(aLimitStartPosition).limit(aLimitNumberResults).sort(aSortObj);
        }
        else
        {
          resultObj = collection.find(query, filter).skip(aLimitStartPosition).limit(aLimitNumberResults);
        }
      }
    }

    return resultObj;
  }
```

Code (code that invoques the previous method and cycles the results):

```
dbCursor = (DBCursor) getMongoData(super.getMainDatabaseName(), aCollectionName, aQueryObj, aSortObj, false, aFilterObj);
      if (dbCursor != null)
      {
        int i = 0;

        while (dbCursor.hasNext())
        {
          DBObject dbObject = dbCursor.next();

          logger.debug("SEARCH FINISHED COUNT: " + dbCursor.count() + "\t CURRENT: " + i);
          i++;
        }
      }
```

Any idea why this happens?

Thank you

Comment: You need to show some code here to give everyone a concept of what you are doing and also explain what you are trying to achive. If you explain the problem properly as to what end result you need to get from source data, then people here can possible suggest better approaches. No code, so scenario, no helpful answer to you.

Comment: Fair enough, here's the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since **$or** function only queries by one parameter (**_id**), I started using **$in** and the problem is solved

https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/

[image]